# Calculating percentage from two SQL Count() results

Tags: sql, count, percentage

I need to count the percentage of finalized transactions compared to total transactions (e.g. including in-process and finalized transactions). From looking around the web, I arrived at:

```
SELECT 100 * (SELECT COUNT(transaction_id) from t_transaction_main   
WHERE due_date = '2016-05-16' and (suspend_status !='' OR
close_date != '0-0000-00'))/COUNT(transaction_id) from t_transaction_main as test;
```

And it worked thus far; however, while the finalized transaction query is as intended, I actually need to divide it by the transaction only on a particular date (here, 2016-05-16). But when I added a WHERE clause...

```
SELECT 100 * (SELECT COUNT(transaction_id) from t_transaction_main   
WHERE due_date = '2016-05-16' and (suspend_status !='' OR
close_date !='0-0000-00'))/COUNT(transaction_id) WHERE due_date = '2016-05-16' from t_transaction_main as test;
```

It immediately stopped working and returned a syntax error. I've also tried wrapping the `COUNT(transaction_id) WHERE due_date = '2016-05-16'` inside parentheses, but it didn't help.

Any solution would be welcomed, thank you.

Comment: you use WHERE due_date before FROM statement in 2nd Query.

Comment: @ChanomFirst thank you, I've corrected it, but it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong clause sequence you put the where before the from clause

```
SELECT 100 * (SELECT COUNT(transaction_id) 
        from t_transaction_main   
        WHERE due_date = '2016-05-16' and (suspend_status !='' OR
  close_date !='0-0000-00'))/COUNT(transaction_id) 
FROM t_transaction_main as test 
WHERE due_date = '2016-05-16' ;
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. The proper syntax order always trips me off.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a subquery?  Or even two aggregation functions?

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN suspend_status <> '' OR close_date <> '0-0000-00'
                THEN 100.0 ELSE 0
           END)
FROM t_transaction_main test 
WHERE due_date = '2016-05-16' ;
```

This is *much* simpler than your original query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of using the WHERE in the second query as the sub query only returning these dates anyway

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause needs to go after the final `from t_transaction_main as test`